# Batch file finding a filename which contains a substring

Tags: batch-file

I want to write a batch file to find all .vsdm files and the file name must contain a substring "2.4". But my code is telling me that all my .vsdm files contains the substring "2.4" which is not correct.

```
FOR /R %completepath% %%G IN (*.vsdm) DO (
set file=%%~nG

If not "%file%"=="%file:2.4=%" (
    echo Filename contains 2.4
) else (
    echo Filename does NOT contains 2.4
)
)
```

Can anyone tell me where did I get it wrong?Thanks

Comment: See delayedexpansion in `For /?` and `setlocal /?`. And `set /?` also discusses it. Basically use `!file!` not `%file%`.

Comment: `dir /a /s "c:\*2.4*.vsdm"` will do what you want quickly.

Comment: see also `forfiles` command. (which is a bit like unix `find`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If "%file%"=="%file:2.4=%" (
    echo Filename "%file%" does NOT contain 2.4
) else (
    echo Filename "%file%" contains 2.4
)
```

Including the filename in the `echo` may reveal more. I can see no reason for the double-negative approach. The way the code operates may depend on precisely where in code the instructions are located, for instance if these lines are contained within any variety of loop or code-block, operation may depend on other elements, so it's important to present the code in-context and with an example of what was expected and what actually happened.

---

correct fomatting makes all clear.

There are one or two SO articles about `delayed expansion` which OP should become familiar with.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /R %completepath% %%G IN (*.vsdm) DO (
set "file=%%~nG"

If not "!file!"=="!file:2.4=!" (
    echo Filename contains 2.4
) else (
    echo Filename does NOT contains 2.4
)
)
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: The first line (and last line) of code isn't formatted as code. It's in a `FOR` loop.

Comment: he asked to find not check

Comment: @HassanUddin : True, but the original code is clearly aimed at checking the filenames found by the `for` loop and the narrative indicates the the perceived problem with the existing code is that the check-for-string appears to fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command ***[Where /?](http://ss64.com/nt/where.html)*** that let you use wildcard characters ( ? * ) and UNC paths.

```dos
@echo off
Title Find the location of a file with substring by Hackoo
Color 0A
Call :inputbox "Enter the file name to search :" "Enter the file name to search"
If  "%input%" == ""  Color 0C & (
    echo(
    echo       You must enter a filename to continue with this program
    pause>nul & exit
) else (
    Call :Browse4Folder "Select the source folder to scan %input%" "c:\scripts"
)
Set "ROOT=%Location%"
::We check whether the input string has an anti-Slach in the end or no ? if yes, we remove it !
IF %ROOT:~-1%==\ SET ROOT=%ROOT:~0,-1%

set whereCmd=where.exe /r %ROOT% %input%
for /f %%a in ('%whereCmd%') do echo %%~nxa --^> %%a
pause & exit
::***************************************************************************
:Browse4Folder
set Location=
set vbs="%temp%\_.vbs"
set cmd="%temp%\_.cmd"
for %%f in (%vbs% %cmd%) do if exist %%f del %%f
for %%g in ("vbs cmd") do if defined %%g set %%g=
(
    echo set shell=WScript.CreateObject("Shell.Application"^) 
    echo set f=shell.BrowseForFolder(0,"%~1",0,"%~2"^) 
    echo if typename(f^)="Nothing" Then  
    echo wscript.echo "set Location=Dialog Cancelled" 
    echo WScript.Quit(1^)
    echo end if 
    echo set fs=f.Items(^):set fi=fs.Item(^) 
    echo p=fi.Path:wscript.echo "set Location=" ^& p
)>%vbs%
cscript //nologo %vbs% > %cmd%
for /f "delims=" %%a in (%cmd%) do %%a
for %%f in (%vbs% %cmd%) do if exist %%f del /f /q %%f
for %%g in ("vbs cmd") do if defined %%g set %%g=
goto :eof
::***************************************************************************
:InputBox
set "input="
set "heading=%~2"
set "message=%~1"
echo wscript.echo inputbox(WScript.Arguments(0),WScript.Arguments(1)) >"%temp%\input.vbs"
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('cscript //nologo "%temp%\input.vbs" "%message%" "%heading%"') do ( 
    set "input=%%a"
)
exit /b
::***************************************************************************
```